# why sed command fail with regex

Tags: bash, sed

I am using this command

```
sed ':a ;{N;/\n/,/};ba'
```

it is showing error in regex.kindly help to identify this problem.

**Full command**

```
SAMPLE_LIST=$ (ls*fastq.gz| awk -F"_" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | sed ':a ;{N;/\n/,/};ba')
```

**Error** bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Similarly another command..

```
FILE_List= $(ls merged_reads2/*/*join.fastq | sed ' :a ; {N;/\n/,/};ba')
```

**error** sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated address regex

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, bash is failing before sed can do anything because of the space between `$` and `(`. (There's also a missing space after `ls`).

The sed command makes no sense: `a1,a2` is the syntax to introduce an "address range". An address can be a match, so `/\n/` is one (which never matches, because the newlines are not part of the line contents sed matches against), but `/` is not a valid address. What are you trying to match?

Comment: Thanks alot for your prompt reply. I corrected this space issue and first command now shows exactly the same error as the second one.  Can you please explain this a1,a2 that you mentioned. Actually I am trying to match the names of directories with  their files.

Comment: `a1,a2` is an address range. An address can be a line number or a match, for example `1,10` limits the following command or block to lines 1 to 10, and `/begin/,/end/` limits it to the range of lines between the strings "begin" and "end".

Comment: It also makes no sense to match `\n`. `sed` operates on one line at a time, and the line never includes the newline character itself.

Comment: Can you share the output of below command ?

    ls*fastq.gz| awk -F"_" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq

Comment: sparrow the out put is as follows: control2
SR-1St-11
SR-2St-12
SR-4St-14
SR-5St-15
SR-6St-16     in these commands problem arises when sed is added.